# Multi Dimensional Array as Function parameter in C

Tags: c, gcc, cmd

I am writing a C program where I want to take Multi Dimensional Array as Function Parameter .

```
void myFunc (int n , int mArray[][n]){
//code
}
```

This way of implementation works in [Online C compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) but when I run the program in Command prompt it gives the following error

```
use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
```

I am using GCC version 7.2.0 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

In *ancient* C (ISO C90) the *inner* array must have a *constant* size (known at compile time, not at run time).

```
void myFunc (int n , int mArray[][5]){
//code
}
```

In *modern* C (starting from ISO C99) variable length arrays are allowed.

The two compilers you tested probably use different standards.

Maybe a compiler switch can help? `-std=c99` for example.